# How can I delegate HTML/CSS/JS to someone while keeping Java code secret?

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

The project uses Spring MVC. HTML views are Freemarker (Java template engine).

If a frontend specialist should work he needs some means of being able to load every page.

I've realized that views are tied to models and it complicates frontend specialized work.

Thinking of REST, ajax, node.js, there isn't any quick fix, is there?
The project mostly passes data via Spring MVC using Controllers into the Model (standard) and then a certain thing gets rendered.

For productive specialized frontend work there needs to be some mock version where just the frontend works and is easily edited in separation.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Why does it have to be a secret? If there's no business case for it, why are you keeping it hidden?

OTOH Frontend work has been drifting to browsers doing more of the heavy lifting, and calling API to return the data. This is a fairly different model compared to the traditional MVC that you may be used to. Do you have more context?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach it's a financial system, its backend is secret and has to stay away (numerous risks incl. the risk of copying the trading strategy or its parts). The context is there are Freemarker templates, CSS, JS and it's a standard Spring MVC project. Do you have a specific additional question? Specialized work on the frontend is useful for every Spring MVC project. A  tool that would take Freemarker views and allow to mock controllers for the frontend work incl. running it in the browser would be nice. Maybe node.js or otherwise.

Comment: @AllenHacks, what do you mean "mock controllers"? What kind of separation are you trying to achieve? Do you want the Freemarker rendering to run in a separate process? Do you just need to make sure that the model passed to it only contains authorized data? I work on military systems and we have some similar scenarios -- I think. I'm still a little confused about what you're asking.

Comment: @CharlesForsythe the goal is to delegate HTML/CSS/JS to someone while keeping Java code secret.  That means HTML,CSS,JS files need to be copied. Model and controllers are secret, hence excluded. A solution is required that will render any view without its original model and controller. If the solution uses node.js it will be better for frontend people. Mock controller: render a freemarker view and replace placeholders with mock data from DB or elsewhere. Frontend work will be done independently of the backend. Frontend will render and be edited with zero backend (clickable links=mock controlrs